# How can I get variable value from a text string?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a constants file with text values, for example:

```
const String loginIntro1 = "Login to account";
const String loginButton = "Login";
```

And I also have a Map containing similar info, for example:

```
{"loginIntro1":"Login to account","loginButton":"Login"}
```

The idea is that the Map (derived from a JSON file) takes precedence, but if the value doesn't exist, the constants value is used instead.

In my text widget, I want to grab the text by a method call, such as:

```
getText('loginIntro1');
```

Is this even possible? How can I get the value from the constants file with a String, rather than a direct reference to the variable? Perhaps I'm missing a much simpler way of achieving this!

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to use a direct reference? I would just use `map['loginIntro1'] ?? loginIntro1` for example wherever I would need it

Comment: Thanks, that's an option. Though I'd have liked to minimise repeating the String, as this is going to happen hundreds of times in the app, passing just one reference through to a method which does the work.

Comment: yeah okay, that's understandable. It's probably possible using reflection, but I'm not familiar with it so I can't provide a solution

Comment: Maybe you can just simply create a new map with all of the needed keys, fill its values with primary map, and simply fill the rest with constants file.

Comment: You can not reference a variable using a string value. That would require code that reads over another code, which is a case of meta-programming.